# Error in reading data in aws data pipeline activity from s3 bucket

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3, boto, amazon-data-pipeline

We have AWS data pipeline where we have an activity (python script) which reads/writes data from/to s3 bucket. We have noticed recently a failure in an activity where the read from s3 fails due to closing of socket connection. The error is intermittent. The failure happens exactly at the same line of the script.

```
read_buff = key_file.read(1024)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/s3/keyfile.py", line 89, in read
  return self.key.read(size)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/s3/key.py", line 373, in read
  data = self.resp.read(size)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/connection.py", line 414, in read
  return httplib.HTTPResponse.read(self, amt):
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/httplib.py", line 561, in read
  s = self.fp.read(amt)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/socket.py", line 380, in read
  data = self._sock.recv(left)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/ssl.py", line 241, in recv
  return self.read(buflen)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/ssl.py", line 160, in read
  return self._sslobj.read(len)

error: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

In our code, we read data from s3 in 1KB chunks. The failure happens in the middle of reading from a file in s3. Does anyone know if there is an upper limit on the number of connections allowed from an EC2 instance to s3 bucket?

Comment: Which os version? Have you seen http://scie.nti.st/2008/3/14/amazon-s3-and-connection-reset-by-peer/? Do you update the same file you're reading?

Comment: @alko: Thanks for your response. I am running this from EC2 instance where the OS is based on kernel 3.4.43. I was not aware of the post you sent me. I will give it a try.

Comment: I tried setting tcp window size parameters but that did not fix the problem. I wonder if there is a way to determine if s3 allows a fixed number of socket connections from a given EC2 instance. I have been doing some research on this online but have not found anything.